# How to use .NET Regex to express positive numbers with decimal

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can use regular express to express the **positive** amount with **most 20** digits in integral and **6** decimals, such as 0.25, 1234566789.123456?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ should at least get you half way there.

Comment: What do you want to do and why Regex ?

Comment: You mean 20 digits including decimals? But isnt this a bit strange behaviour? YOu cannot chnage the number - number it is what it is. You can only change number of decimals, but not the whole number.

Comment: You might want to use [specific Xml Schema types](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp) (if in a XSD schema), or `decimal.TryParse` instead.  Any regex will probably be sloppy, since decimal doesn't guarantees a specific number of digits, but a max storage that will validly hold your decimal value.

Comment: please try to re-word the question more clearly. It's quite hard to be certain what you're actually trying to ask.

Answer (score 3):

```
var regexStr = @"^\d{1,20}(\.\d{1,6})?$";
var r = Regex.Match("15", regexStr); // match 15
r = Regex.Match("15.158", regexStr); // match 15.158
r = Regex.Match("-22.9", regexStr); // fail, negative
r = Regex.Match("123456789012345678901.1234567", regexStr); // fail, too long
r = Regex.Match("-123456789012345601.123456", regexStr); // fail, negative
r = Regex.Match("123456789012345601.123456", regexStr); // match 123456789012345601.123456
```

Comment: Why the `(-){0}`? Without that it still won't match a negative number.

Comment: `(-){0}` makes absolutely no sense here. 1. No need for a capturing group. 2. If you don't allow it, why write it down? `@"^\d{1,20}(\.\d{1,6})?$"` will do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
^\d{1,20}(.\d{1,6})?$

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<![-\d\.])  \d{1,20} (\.\d{1,6})? \b
```

Test cases:
    0.25, 1234566789.123456, 5.66,  -12345678901234567890.1,   12345678901234567890.1, 5

Answer (score 0):

There you go : @"^[0-9]{1,20}(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$"

Comment: This regex validates ".1" as false which is a valid number in C#